# Mod Rewrite Clean URL's

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

How can I transform:

- http://example.com/about.php
- http://example.com/hello/deep.php
- http://example.com/hello/world/deeper.php

Dynamically, into URLs like:

- http://example.com/about/
- http://example.com/hello/deep/
- http://example.com/hello/world/deeper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://gist.github.com/22877